# Input from stream to enum type

Tags: c++, enums, istream

How to input from stream to enum type?

I can do it so

```
unsigned int sex = 0;
stream >> sex;
student.m_bio.sex = static_cast<Sex>(sex);
```

Otherwise?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
inline std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & str, Sex & v) {
  unsigned int sex = 0;
  if (str >> sex)
    v = static_cast<Sex>(sex);
  return str;
}
```

If you want to ensure that the value is valid, you can do something like this:

```
enum Sex {
    Male,
    Female,
    Sex_COUNT
};

inline std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & str, Sex & v) {
  unsigned int sex = 0;
  if (!(str >> sex))
    return str;
  if (sex >= Sex_COUNT) {
    str.setstate(str.rdstate() | std::ios::failbit);
    return str;
  }
  v = static_cast<Sex>(sex);
  return str;
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `v = static_cast<Sex>(sex);`... that is, the argument to the cast is `sex`, not `v`. :D

Comment: This answer is missing a `return str;`.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Thanks, fixed, now I'll go make some more coffee - seems I need it :P

Comment: Too bad enum's don't have an `is_valid` function.

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y: Who is using `is_valid` in the first place?

Comment: @Nawaz, nobody is using it here, I just meant it would be nice to have such a function. It'd be very convenient to say `Sex.is_valid(sex)`

Answer (score 4):

This question was asked in a more general form over here: [How to read enums from a std::istream in a generic fashion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177580/how-to-read-enums-from-a-stdistream-in-a-generic-fashion).
The OP almost had a working solution as it was; he just had some trouble with `const`, and a few unnecessary angle-brackets. Here's the working solution fleshed out:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

enum enSide { eLeft, eRight };
enum enType { eConUndefined, eConRoom };

template<typename Enum>
class EnumReader
{
    Enum& e_;

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, const EnumReader& val) {
      typename std::underlying_type<Enum>::type asInt;
      if (in >> asInt) val.e_ = static_cast<Enum>(asInt);
      return in;
    }
  public:
    EnumReader(Enum& e) : e_(e) {}
};

template<typename Enum>
EnumReader<Enum> read_enum(Enum& e)
{
    return EnumReader<Enum>(e);
}

class MyClass {
    enSide mSide;
    enType mType;
    int mTargetId;
  public:
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, MyClass& val) {
        in >> read_enum(val.mSide) >> read_enum(val.mType) >> val.mTargetId;
        return in;
    }
};
```

The `read_enum` function template serves the same purpose here as `std::make_pair` or `std::make_shared` in the standard library: it lets us dispense with the angle brackets. You could equally well write `in >> EnumReader<enSide>(val.mSide) >> EnumReader<enType>(val.mType)`, but that's more typing (pun intended).

A few vendors' standard libraries are allegedly still missing `std::underlying_type` from their `<type_traits>` headers. If you have one of these incomplete libraries, you can use one of the workarounds listed at [How to know underlying type of class enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343329/how-to-know-underlying-type-of-class-enum).

Answer (score 1):

This is not pretty but should do it

```
stream >>  reinterpret_cast<std::underlying_type<Sex>::type &>(student.m_bio.sex);
```

Cheers,
CC