# How to know underlying type of class enum?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a variable declared as:

```
enum class FooEnum: uint64_t {}
```

and I would like to cast to its base-type, but I don't want to hardcode the base-type. For instance, something like this:

```
FooEnum myEnum;
uint64_t * intPointer = (underlying_typeof(myEnum))&myEnum;
```

Is this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast casting, specifically dynamic

Comment: @L7ColWinters `dynamic_cast` can't help. Don't let the `class` keyword and the `: uint64_t` mislead you into thinking that scoped enumerations and underlying types of enumerations are similar to class inheritance.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Since C++ 11** you can use this:

- [**`std::underlying_type`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type) class template to know the underlying type of enum.

The [doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type) says,

> Defines a member `typedef` type of *type* that is the underlying type for the enumeration T.

So you should be able to do this:

```
#include <type_traits> //include this

FooEnum myEnum;
auto pointer = static_cast<std::underlying_type<FooEnum>::type*>(&myEnum);
```

**In C++ 14** it has been a bit simplified (note there is no `::type`):

```
auto pointer = static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<FooEnum>*>(&myEnum);
```

And finally **since C++ 23** one can get value without explicit cast ([docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_underlying)):

```
auto value = std::to_underlying<FooEnum>(myEnum);
```

Comment: Would a `static_cast` work?  I was under the impression that no sane casts would work on a `enum class`.

Answer (score 20):

Your guessed syntax is amazingly close.  You're looking for `std::underlying_type` in `<type_traits>`:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

enum class FooEnum: std::uint64_t {};

int main()
{
    FooEnum myEnum;
    uint64_t* intPointer = (std::underlying_type<FooEnum>::type*)&myEnum;
}
```

Comment: So close indeed. Apparently an appropriate name was chosen. :)

Comment: I dont get it. If `intPointer`is declared to be `uint64_t*`, then why don't you simply use it in the cast expression as well? Why bother using `std::underlying_type<FooEnum>::type*` at all? (Also, C-style cast is bad, is another topic).

Answer (score 9):

Both Visual C++ 10.0 and MinGW g++ 4.6.1 lack **`std::underlying_type`**, but both accept this code:

```
template< class TpEnum >
struct UnderlyingType
{
    typedef typename conditional<
        TpEnum( -1 ) < TpEnum( 0 ),
        typename make_signed< TpEnum >::type,
        typename make_unsigned< TpEnum >::type
        >::type T;
};
```

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf @Grizzly: However, casts `TpEnum(-1)` and `TpEnum(0)` *may* have UB: 5.2.9 "Static cast", item 10 says " A value of integral or enumeration type can be explicitly converted to an enumeration type. The value is unchanged if the original value is within the range of the enumeration values (7.2). Otherwise, the resulting value is unspeciﬁed (and might not be in that range)."

Comment: @Joker_vD: unspecified is not UB.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach for when underlying_type is not present.  This method doesn't attempt to detect the signed-ness of the enum, just give you a type of the same size, which is more than enough for a lot of situations.

```
template<int>
class TIntegerForSize
{
    typedef void type;
};

template<>
struct TIntegerForSize<1>
{
    typedef uint8_t type;
};

template<>
struct TIntegerForSize<2>
{
    typedef uint16_t type;
};

template<>
struct TIntegerForSize<4>
{
    typedef uint32_t type;
};

template<>
struct TIntegerForSize<8>
{
    typedef uint64_t type;
};

template<typename T>
struct TIntegerForEnum
{
    typedef typename TIntegerForSize<sizeof(T)>::type type;
};
```

Usage:

```
enum EFoo {Alpha, Beta};
EFoo f = Alpha;
TIntegerForEnum<EFoo>::type i = f;
TIntegerForEnum<decltype(f)>::type j = f;
```