# Underlying type of a C++ enum in C++03

Tags: c++, std, type-traits

Is there a way to get the equivalent of std::underlying_type in C++03 compilers?

I'm aware of some support in boost::type_traits, but there is no fully functional converter there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10956467/2411320) solution?

```
template< class TpEnum >
struct UnderlyingType
{
    typedef typename conditional<
        TpEnum( -1 ) < TpEnum( 0 ),
        typename make_signed< TpEnum >::type,
        typename make_unsigned< TpEnum >::type
        >::type type;
};
```

You can find the building blocks for it (conditional, make_signed, make_unsigned in boost::type_traits)

Comment: That's a very fancy way to implement underlying_tpye in a C++11 compiler... However, I do have a C++03 compiler, without conditionals or make_signed

Comment: I was just thinking about that @sammy! `make_signed` required C++11. Sorry. Should I delete my answer? :/

Comment: And what about `make_signed` @BillyONeal? :/ I can't think of a way to implement it without using C++11.

Comment: All your constructs are available in Boost, and I've been able to build my UnderlyingType. Thanks!

Comment: @G.Samaras: You make a primary template that typedefs `T` to `type`, and explicit specializations for `char`, `short`, `int`, etc. which typedef `unsigned char`, `unsigned short`, `unsigned int`, etc. as `type`.

Comment: I see @BillyONeal, pretty much like the last answer provided in my link. Glad you found a workaround sammy, after my answer! :)

Comment: `TpEnum( -1 )` invokes undefined behavior if `TpEnum`'s smallest enumerator is non-negative