# How to read enums from a std::istream in a generic fashion

Tags: c++, templates, enums, iostream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Input from stream to enum type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633784/input-from-stream-to-enum-type)

I have several classes with different enums as class members and I want to read the classes from a stream.

The following code shows an exemplary class:

```
  enum enSide{
    eLeft,
    eRight
  };

  enum enType{
    eConUndefined,
    eConRoom    
  };

  class MyClass{
    public:
      friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, MyClass& val) {
        in >> val.mSide >> val.mType >> val.mTargetId;        
        return in;      
      }

      MyClass(){}

    private:
      enSide mSide;
      enType mType;
      int mTargetId; 
  };
```

**Unfortunately this does not work since direct reading into an `enum` Value is not possible (no template for >>).**

Thus I created a helper class:

```
template<class ENUM>
class ScanTo{
  public:
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, ScanTo<ENUM>& eval) {
      unsigned int val;
      in >> val;
      eval.mrEnum = static_cast<ENUM>(val);
      return in;      
    }

    ScanTo(ENUM& eRef):mrEnum(eRef){}

  private:
    ENUM& mrEnum;    
};
```

Now I can write the code for reading `MyClass` as follows:

```
friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, MyClass& val) {
  ScanTo<enSide> scanside(val.mSide);
  ScanTo<enType> scantype(val.mType);
  in >> scanside >> scantype >> val.mTargetId;        
  return in;      
}
```

This is already not far from what I wanted but still needs two indirections over the helper class, which cannot be written as temporarys:

```
friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, MyClass& val) {
 in >>  ScanTo<enSide>(val.mSide)>> ScanTo<enType>(val.mType) >> val.mTargetId;        
 return in;      
}
```

**does not compile (gcc 4.43)**, because a non const reference to a temporary is forbidden as pointed out in the comments.

> So here comes the question:
>
> **Can this be done easier without resorting to some temporaries and templates as done above?**

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633784/input-from-stream-to-enum-type

Comment: The condensed version compiles (and works) perfectly with my VS2010. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @dionadar I think VS allows binding temporaries (`ScanTo<enSide>(val.mSide)`) to a reference to non-const (`myClass& val`) by means of an extension. It's non-standard, though.

Comment: @kol: Yes but this means a separate function for every enum. I have loads ;-)

Comment: @dionadar: I use gcc version 4.4.3 and as jrok points out it seems more severe about binding temporaries to non const references

Comment: you could trick the compiler by binding to const reference and use a `const_cast<>()`, though this sounds like a bad solution.

Comment: For those who closed the question: IMHO this is not a duplicate. The referenced question adresses the reading of one singular enum and no generic read function for all enum types

Comment: Posted an answer on the non-closed question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21360718/1424877
@Martin had it just about right; I simply copied his code, fixed the bug that prevented it from compiling, and added a helper function for convenience.

Comment: @Quuxplusone: nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

I think you may write a helper function template:

```
template <class T>
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& is, T& t)
{
    int i;
    is >> i;
    t = (T)i;
    return is;
}
```

which makes

```
in >> val.mSide >> val.mType >> val.mTargetId;
```

possible.

Comment: This kills you since it can be triggered for any arbitrary type. If you forget to define operator >> for your custom type but use it anyway.Your code will compile but typecast an int to any custom type

Answer (score 0):

The best option for you is to define your data members as `int`, and use type safe accessors to set and retrieve them.

```
class MyClass{
  public:
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, MyClass& val) {
      in >> val.mSide >> val.mType >> val.mTargetId;        
      return in;      
    }

    MyClass(){}

    enSide side () const { return static_cast<enSide>(mSide); }
    void side (enSide v) { mSide = v; }

    enType type () const { return static_cast<enType>(mType); }
    void type (enType v) { mType = v; }

    int targetId () const { return mTargetId; }
    void targetId (int v) { mTargetId = v; }

  private:
    int mSide;
    int mType;
    int mTargetId; 
};
```

This avoids the temporaries as you desired.